# Android multiple screen support Normal

Tags: java, android, screen

I have a problem with supporting multiple screens.

3.7 "WVGA is just as normal 4.7" WXGA, it is a normal.

Making a layout for normal screens and let's say I have so arranged buttons:
http://i42.tinypic.com/ebewwy.png

Looks like I want. But if someone has a screen 4.7 "which is also normal.

It now looks like this:
http://i43.tinypic.com/2rqc6xg.png

All buttons are coming up and now I do not fit my concept.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a table layout and putting your buttons in different cells with different alignments.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Comment: I currently have in RelativeLayout buttons. I need to have in this layout because I need the arrow keys to adjust something similar, like this:
http://i44.tinypic.com/10mn6h5.png